# Netbeans Maven Project - Other Sources does not appear

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, directory

In Netbeans-Maven Project, in logical folder Other Sources are usually some textual, xml, etc. Files are stored. Howewer, i do not understand when exactly it is appearing and how to create it while creating a new project.
I tried (the same like for Test Packages with junit test files)

Right click on `Project -> New -> Xml` File or just empty file. The new file is created in the project root (not sources), withoout Other Sources Folder is shown. 
I only want to make the Other Sources folder shown - then, i can move a file there.

Comment: You need to create a folder "resources" in src/main/. NetBeans will recognize it as "Other Soruces" afterwards

Comment: yes IT WORKS!!!!!!! thanks a lot!

Comment: @Clayn you can post this as an answer this can help others :)

Answer (score 14):

You need the folder "resources" under "src/main". You can create it using the explorer or in NetBeans using the tab "Files".

NetBeans will then recognize this folder and display it as "Other Sources".